# Play framework custom headers ignored

Tags: scala, playframework, response-headers

I have this very simple Play controller:

```
@Singleton
class Application @Inject()(cc: ControllerComponents) extends AbstractController(cc) {
  def index = Action {
    Ok(views.html.index(SharedMessages.itWorks))
      .withHeaders("Content-Security-Policy" -> "script-src 'unsafe-eval'")
  }
}
```

But the added header is ignored. The Content Security Policy in the rendered page is the default one:

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have Play!'s security filter enabled? In that case you have to set the CSP header in the `application.conf` configuration file instead of adding it manually.

See [Play! SecurityHeaders](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/SecurityHeaders) for details.